# Make lines dashed in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have the following problems with my code.
1: I want to make every line apart from the mean one dashed and also make the values inside the legend dahed?

2: How do i correctly order the values in the legend?

The plot looks like this:[image]

This is my code:

```
# Colors
num_patterns <- length(unique(df$pat))
num_patterns <- num_patterns + 1
color_palette <- viridis(num_patterns, option = "A")

unique_sc <- unique(df$sc)
result_df <- data.frame(sc = unique_sc, mean_changes = numeric(length(unique_sc)))

for (i in 1:length(unique_sc)) {
  mean_changes <- mean(df$changes[df$sc == unique_sc[i]])
  result_df$mean_changes[i] <- mean_changes
}
result_df$pat = c("Mean","Mean","Mean","Mean","Mean","Mean","Mean","Mean")
names(result_df)[names(result_df) == "mean_changes"] <- "changes"

ggplot(df, aes(x = sc, y = changes, color = pat, shape = pat)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = "dashed"), alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_line(data = result_df, aes(x = sc, y = changes, color = pat), size = 0.6) +
  xlab(TeX("$SC_{Max}$")) +
  ylab("Relative Understaffing %") +
  scale_color_manual(values = color_palette, name = "Pattern") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(mean = 16), name = "Mean") +
  guides(linetype = "none")
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For (1) set `aes(linetype = pat)` and assign linetypes to pat-values with `scale_linetype_manual`, for (2) convert pat from character vector to factor and relevel in the desired order, conveniently with fct_relevel from package {forcats}.

Comment: Thanks. The first part works for making the lines in the plot dashed but not in the legend

Comment: you've turned off the linetype legend ( `guides(linetype = "none")`)

Comment: It now creates a second legend